# Seeking Solutions for Rapid Battery Drain in RHEL Dual Boot Setup: Need Advice on Battery-Efficient Linux Distros

Tags: linux, distributions, gnu, battery

I recently purchased a new laptop and decided to set up a dual boot with RHEL. Having used Fedora for over 1.5 years and enjoying the experience, I thought of giving RHEL a try. However, upon starting RHEL, I noticed a significant drain on my battery. For example, on Windows using battery power, I can work for up to 3-4 hours, maybe even more, for tasks like listening to music on Spotify and browsing the web. On the other hand, in RHEL (or Fedora), without any active tasks, my battery drops to 10 percent within just 30 minutes.

I am not inclined to purchase a desktop solely for Linux use, and I also want to avoid wearing down my battery. How can I resolve this issue? Are there more battery-efficient and stable distros that you would recommend?

Any when this problem for GNU/Linux will be solved?

NOTE: In my old laptop I had also the same problem but I don't want to use it anymore.

My specs:

```
------------------
System Information
------------------
      System Manufacturer: LENOVO
                     BIOS: UEFI
                Processor: 13th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-13700HX (24 CPUs), ~2.1GHz
                   Memory: 16384MB RAM
      Available OS Memory: 16124MB RAM
Microsoft Graphics Hybrid: Supported

---------------
Display Devices
---------------
           Chip type: Intel(R) UHD Graphics Family
            DAC type: Internal

           Chip type: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4060 Laptop GPU
            DAC type: Integrated RAMDAC
```

This happens even in power saving mode. I don't remember the exact kernel, but I think it's newer than 6.0.0.

> Do you use the performance CPU governor?

I don't know how to know that...but I have deleted the RHEL from the dual boot...so I think I can test it atm.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us more detail. What is your hardware? Do you have discrete graphics? Do you use the performance CPU governor? What kernel are you using? We can't help if all we know is "some laptop using RedHat".

Comment: @terdon I have updated the OP.

Comment: Hypotheses: This is happening because in Linux you're using the Nvidia dGPU all the time. Other Windows optimizations notwithstanding - optimizations that always give Windows and advantage in power saving - such differences are typically chalked to "incorrect" usage of hybrid graphics. Open Nvidia X Server Settings (requires correct version of Nvidia drivers installed and in use) and then select the "power saving mode (Intel)" and reboot. TEST and report back.

Comment: @ChanganAuto But this problem happens even I don't load the Nvidia GPU.

Comment: So, to be clear, you're saying that you did the aforementioned procedure to select and use only the iGPU and the issue persists? And which Nvidia driver version? It must the the latest one for GTX4060...

Comment: Not exactly....I mean that I have never installed the Nvidia drivers..so I was using intel GPU...I think the problem is about something else but I dont know what it is..